# Problem configuring Sendgrid as SMTP Relay Server for Firebase Authentication Email

Tags: html, firebase, smtp, sendgrid, content-type

community!

I'm configuring **Sendgrid** as **SMTP** for Firebase Authentication Email but when I try to send an email the server sends it with content-type: text/plain

So the **HTML content** is not recognized when the user receives it

When default SMTP Firebase service sends the email with Content-Type: multipart/alternative the html content **is recognized**

So, **Why** do I need to change the default SMTP firebase service?

Basically, because when SMTP firebase service is set up as sender some emails are not received with a good reputation so they are identified as **SPAM** so that is why I need to change the SMTP service to Sendgrid.

[Current Firebase SMTP configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PSIq.png)

I have looked into the SendGrid documentation but I did not find useful resources for fix this.

I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**FIREBASE/MAILGUN HTML SETTINGS**

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
2. Under "Step 1", select "**Firebase Dynamic Links API v1**" as the scope
3. Click "**Authorize APIs**" and log into the Google Account assocaited with your Firebase App
4. Under "Step 2", click "**Exchange authorization code for tokens**"
5. Under "Step 3", change HTTP method to **PATCH**
6. Enter the Request URI `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/*{FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}*/config?updateMask=notification.sendEmail.resetPasswordTemplate.bodyFormat` (Add your project ID in there!)
7. Click "**Enter request body**" and input `{notification:{sendEmail:{resetPasswordTemplate:{bodyFormat: "HTML"}}}}` and click "Close" at the bottom.
8. Click "**Send the request**"

If you get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` within the response, job done.
You can now send HTML emails using Firebase using Sendgrid, Mailgun or any other email service!